# Exception in thread "Animation Thread" processing.core.PApplet$RendererChangeException

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, opengl, processing

I try to run the Java class in Eclipse on my Mac:

```
import processing.core.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;

public class LifeExpectancy extends PApplet {
    UnfoldingMap map;

    public void setup() {}

    public void draw() {
        size(800, 600, OPENGL);
        map = new UnfoldingMap(this, 50, 50, 700, 500, new Google.GoogleMapProvider());
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" processing.core.PApplet$RendererChangeException
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1789)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1746)
    at module2.LifeExpectancy.draw(LifeExpectancy.java:16)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2390)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:245)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2260)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I found at Google that I need to add all the OpenGL libraries to my build path. For example, here:
https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/2931/build-in-eclipse-using-opengl-fails

I did this but I still get the same error. Here is my build path for the project:
[image: Build Path]

Could you advice me please what else should I do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing stuff in the `draw()` function that belongs in the `setup()` function. Specifically, you should only call `size()` **once**, as the first line in your `setup()` function. On top of that, you probably only need to create your map once as well.

```
import processing.core.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;

public class LifeExpectancy extends PApplet {
    UnfoldingMap map;

    public void setup() {
        size(800, 600, OPENGL);
        map = new UnfoldingMap(this, 50, 50, 700, 500, new Google.GoogleMapProvider());
    }

    public void draw() {
        //draw your map
    }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! :[ Thank you, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for Processing3.x, the above will not work, as the size() function should be called in settings(), as follows:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Template extends PApplet {

    public void settings() {

        size(800, 600, ...);
    }

    public void setup() {

    }

    public void draw() {

        background(0, 30, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PApplet.main(new String[] { Template.class.getName() });
    }
}
```